# Python separating list (discord.py bot)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, bots, discord.py

### Info

I'm trying to separate a list of independent variables, but my list is changing (the number of things on the list is changing). I tried

```
var1, var2, var3 = mylist
```

but it works only when ***my_list*** have 3 "items", but it won't have 3 items every time, sometimes the amount will change. I'm trying to make a discord bot that collects ids from voice channels and uses them in command "*client.get_channel()*" which only accepts one id. I will use it to check who is connected to my voice channels.

### Goal

I want to separate a list to independent variables, even when the list sometimes has a different amount/quantity of "items".

---

### My idea for solution

I was thinking about making a script that would count items (ex. ***len(my_list)***) on my list and make enough variables, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: What's your purpose behind doing that? Knowing that might help give you a solution. What can you do with separate variables that you cannot with a list?

Comment: Why do you want them separated out into variables? Why not just use the list as is? What *problem are you actually trying to solve*?

Comment: You *already have* names for each of the items in the list.  They are `mylist[0]`, `mylist[1]`, `mylist[2]`, and so on.

Comment: Do you want the first three elements as separate variables, no matter how many elements the list has, or do you want _n_ separate variables for each element in the list? For the first case, use `a, b, c = lst[:3]` or `a, b, c, *_ = lst`, and for the latter case, just use the list itself.

Comment: As I see it: first you have problem how to create variables dynamically. After solving that you will face next problem - how to access variables created dynamically.....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables) tl;dr you actually want a list

Comment: This appears to be an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: I'm making discord bot which gives me channels ids which I need to use separately in my code to count members in each channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting elements of a list to separate variables won't achieve anything useful. If you want to reference them individually, then you can already do that:

```py
mylist[0]
mylist[1]
... #and so on
```

If you're hoping to assign variables for these values for better readability (i.e. maybe `mylist[0]` always refers to a user's name) then use objects instead of lists and call `user.name`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with what you're proposing is that you're dynamically creating local variables. If you do that, you can't be deterministic in your code. If you have 4 elements in a list and you create `var1, var2, var3, var4`, and then later there are 5 elements, what do you do with your code?

Having said that, you can dynamically create variables at runtime. It's just probably not a good idea:

```py
>>> my_list = [1,2,3,4]
```

I have a list of 4 items. I can create var_0, var_1, etc based on it, at runtime, by assigning elements to the `locals()` dict:

```
>>> for i, element in enumerate(my_list):
...     locals()[f'var_{i}'] = element
... 
>>> var_0
1
>>> var_1
2
>>> var_2
3
>>> var_3
4
>>> var_4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'var_4' is not defined
```

Notice that if my list were one element longer, `var_4` would have been defined.